# Using one parameter in a macro as a whole C++ instruction

Tags: c++, macros, arduino

**EDIT: The code marked as "not working" was actually working. It was because of a syntax problems in my tests, not detected by the compiler. So the question is already solved, thank you.**

C++ is not a language I use everyday, so it is possible that the solution is trivial.

About the context first. I use C++ to develop on a microcontroller (Arduino-based, [AVR microcontroller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR)), so I do not use the [STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library), printf-like functions, new/malloc should be avoided and C++ <string> too.

I have an object called `Serial` similar to the C++ cout iostream, to communicate with the microcontroller with a serial interface. I have overloaded the "<<" operator of the class from which `Serial` is an instance so I can do something like that:

```
Serial << "debug " << "value is " << 3 << endl;

// Whithout the << operator it would be:
Serial.print("debug ");
Serial.print("value is ");
Serial.println(3);
```

I would like to create a function (or a macro) that enables this kind of line only if debugging is enabled, and which automatically add the "debug" string and append the "endl" value at the end.

So something like that (warning, code does not work because "data" cannot expand as a whole C++ instruction):

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define PRINT_DEBUG(data) do {Serial << "debug " << data << endl;} while(0)
#else
    #define PRINT_DEBUG(data) do {} while(0)
#endif

// This code works
PRINT_DEBUG("hello world");

// This code does not work
int value1 = 3;
char * value2 = "this is a string";
PRINT_DEBUG("sensor1 value:" << value1 << " other sensor value " << value2);
```

This kind of function/macro would allow me to easily output strings on my serial interface with a specific "string protocol" without having to repeat the "debug" string at the start. It would also allow me to easily disable the print of debug message by not setting the DEBUG macro. I also have only one "#ifdef DEBUG" instead of several ones in my code.

I managed to do something like that with [variadic arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic), but I hate this solution because it is dangerous to use (I do not want to specify the number of arguments), and I cannot mix different type of data:

```
void __rawSend(char * args, ...) {
    Serial.print(args);
    va_list paramList;
    va_start (paramList, args);
    while(true) {
        char * next = va_arg(paramList, char*);
        if (next == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        Serial.print(" ");
        Serial.print(next);
    }
    Serial.println();
    va_end(paramList);
}

#ifdef DEBUG
    #define printDebug(...) do {__rawSend(OUTPUT_DEBUG, __VA_ARGS__, NULL);} while(0)
#else
    #define printDebug(...) do {} while(0)
#endif

int intValue = 1;
char * stringValue = "data";

// This works
printDebug("hello",stringValue);
// This does not works
printDebug("data is", intValue);
```

How can I do that? Is it possible with macros (while avoiding variadic arguments and mixing different kind of types)? Is there a better solution?

Comment: "doesn't work" is a bit cryptic. What happened when you tried it the trivial way (the first example)?

Comment: Do you hate `printf` for some reasons ? Well ... I agree it's not typesafe, but it would crush the problem (I think).

Comment: @J.N.: read the beginning of the question.

Comment: What error do you get when using the first method you describe?

Comment: @J.N: 2 problems for printf: first it adds lots of weight in the binary (I work on a microcontroller), and second it is not compatible with a "String" object provided by the Arduino library. The "Serial" object already knows how to process Arduino String, char, int, ...

Comment: I checked `PRINT_DEBUG()` macro appraoach and it worked fine on VS2010 (qualifing `std::endl` and using `std::cout` were the only changes I made.)

Comment: @VincentHiribarren : the code you label as not working, works on MSVC 2010. Your preprocessor may be outdated / limited.

Comment: I'm almost inclined to say "your `operator<<` has some problem" (without ever having seen it). The reason for that is that a macro does nothing but paste text, and if you manually copy/paste the text in the "does not work" example above (substituting `data` with `"sensor1 value:" << value1 << " other sensor value " << value2´, you get a line that should very clearly work.

Comment: @hmjd: it is not the endl of the std namespace. Anyway if I do not append the end with "endl" I still have an error.

Comment: @adamk: I have the following error for the line "DEBUG("hello" << " " << "world");" : invalid operands of types 'const char [6]' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator<<'

Comment: `PRINT_DEBUG()`, not `DEBUG()`.

Comment: @hmjd: oh no... I am ashamed of myself :-) I mixed my tests. So the code works with PRINT_DEBUG. It was compiling because DEBUG is an existing macro. Thank you all, I will check how I can close the question / mark it resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry all, the code marked as "not working" does actually work. It was because of a syntax problems in my tests, not detected by the compiler.

Anyway, my solution can benefit other people working with Arduino, as I have seen solutions using printf or trying to recreate printf.

I used the "<<" operator coming from http://arduiniana.org/libraries/streaming/

Answer (score 1):

I tend to avoid macros for this sort of things and use classes and static polymoprhism instead :

```
// Define different types providing a stream interface
struct DebugStream
{
  template <typename T>
  std::ostream & operator<< (const T & x) const {
    return Serial << "debug " << x;
  }

  // This one is for stream manipulators
  std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream& (*x) (std::ostream&)) const {
    return Serial << "debug " << x;
  }
};


// This type also provides a stream-like interface but does nothing
struct NoStream
{
  template <class T>
  const NoStream & operator<< (const T & x) const { 
    return *this;
  }

  const NoStream & operator<< (std::ostream& (*x) (std::ostream&)) const {
    return *this;
  }
};


// Instanciate a debug object having one of the previously defined types
// 
// Make sure to declare debug in a common .hxx file included everywhere else
// but to define it only once in a .cxx file.
#ifdef DEBUG
DebugStream debug;
#else
NoStream debug;
#endif 


// Use it like you would use the Serial iostream
debug << "value is " << 3 << std::endl;
```

Since everything is inlined and exact types are known at compile-time, the compiler can optimize out all unnecessary operations on NoStream instances.

Comment: Interesting, I also prefer avoiding the use of macro, but I am not comfortable enough with templates to have this kind of solution in mind. The only thing I do not like is that this solution does not append automatically std::endl at the end of a chain of "<<". Is it possible without macros?

Comment: @vincent No, I don't know of any way to automatically append `std::endl` at the end with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problems correctly...
Looks to me like you need to overload operator<< for all types you're going to send to the debug interface.

- The var args macro has to have a way to deduce the types of its arguments.  The way you have it implemented it's expecting all C type strings.  You'd be better off with printf or a library like [fastformat](http://www.fastformat.org/).
- If your `operator<<` is not returning a reference to the class that allows `operator<<` to be chained, you'll get errors like "I have the following error for the line "DEBUG("hello" << " " << "world");" : invalid operands of types 'const char [6]' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator<<' ".  I do not believe `DEBUG("hello" << " " << "world");` can be made to work. `DEBUG( "hello", "world");` might work.